# message.getContent returns null despite being able to get numbers of mails in inbox correctly

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail API to read emails in my Android app. I debugged my app to find that the number of `Message` objects in the array are equal to the number of emails I have in my inbox but I'm always getting `null` when trying to use `getContent` on the `message` object. I'm using the jars found [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/downloads). I'm using imap.gmail.com with all the correct details. I even tried a different email service called mail.com but the error still remains. I'm providing only the method I use to read emails. You can assume everything else is correct.

Code:-

```
private void initMail(String hostval, String mailStrProt, String uname, String pwd, String authEmail, int mode)
{

    uriArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        Log.d("LOGCAT","initMail");
        //Set property values
        Properties propvals = new Properties();
        propvals.put("mail.store.protocol", mailStrProt);
        propvals.put("mail.imap.user", uname);
        propvals.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
        propvals.put("mail.imap.host", hostval);
        propvals.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
        propvals.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session emailSessionObj = Session.getInstance(propvals, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(uname, pwd);
            }
        });
        //Create POP3 store object and connect with the server
        Store storeObj = emailSessionObj.getStore(mailStrProt);
        storeObj.connect(hostval, uname, pwd);
        //Create folder object and open it in read-only mode
        Folder emailFolderObj = storeObj.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolderObj.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        //Fetch messages from the folder and print in a loop
        Message[] messageobjs = emailFolderObj.getMessages();

        for (Message message : messageobjs) {

            if(message.getFrom()[0].toString().equals(authEmail)) {

                if(message.getContent() instanceof String) { Log.d("LOGCAT","String"); uriArrayList.add(stringToUri(message.getContent().toString())); }
                else if(message.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {

                    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart;
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < multipart.getCount() ; i++) {

                        if(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(multipart.getBodyPart(i).getDisposition())) {

                            mimeBodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                            File file = new File(mimeBodyPart.getFileName());
                            mimeBodyPart.saveFile(file);
                            uriArrayList.add(Uri.fromFile(file));

                        }

                    }

                }

                lastReceivedMailDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

            }

        }
        //Now close all the objects
        emailFolderObj.close(false);
        storeObj.close();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

EDIT:

```
for (Message message : messageobjs) {

            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < multipart.getCount() ; i++) {

                    mimeBodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                    File file = new File(mimeBodyPart.getFileName()); //line number 204
                    mimeBodyPart.saveFile(file); 
                    uriArrayList.add(Uri.fromFile(file));



            } }
```

Comment: Use the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).  If it still doesn't work, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  Also, you [don't need the Authenticator object at all](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: @BillShannon I was getting an AuthenticationException when I didn't use Authenticator. I tried using the official JavaMail library as well and got the following debug output. https://pastebin.com/xQr5Mkjb

Comment: How do you know getContent is returning null?  I don’t think you’re ever calling it.  Are you sure the from address is really matching?  Also, try getting rid of the Authenticator again and if it fails include the debug output.

Comment: As I said I debugged my program and saw that the content is null and that's why the `uriArrayList` is empty. Check the edit to see I ran the code without the if condition and also the following debug output: https://pastebin.com/KnHDFW5Z

Comment: First, getContent is not always going to return a Multipart, so you need to handle that.  Second, getContent is not returning null.  I don't know how you debugged your program to determine that it's returning null but I don't believe it.  However, getFileName is returning null, which is causing "new File" to fail.  This is clear from the stack trace. Not every part will have a file name.

Comment: It's working now. It was a fault in my part to incorrectly interpret the debugger. Thank you for your time.